Bypass/Workaround for UrlFetchApp Request failed returned code 403
I have this Google Script function that uses the following JSON REST API:
function TESOURODIRETO() {
  let srcURL = "https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/json/br/com/b3/tesourodireto/service/api/treasurybondsinfo.json";
  let jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(srcURL);
}

This function was working fine days ago, but now it returns the following error:

Exception: Request failed for https://www.tesourodireto.com.br
returned code 403. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head><title>Just a moment...</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta htt... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Full HTML (using option muteHttpExceptions: true on UrlFetchApp.fetch()):


<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head><title>Just a moment...</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"><meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><style>*{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0}html{line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;color:#313131}button,html{font-family:system-ui,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Arial,Noto Sans,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji,Segoe UI Symbol,Noto Color Emoji}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){body{background-color:#222;color:#d9d9d9}body a{color:#fff}body a:hover{color:#ee730a;text-decoration:underline}body .lds-ring div{border-color:#999 transparent transparent}body .font-red{color:#b20f03}body .pow-button{background-color:#4693ff;color:#1d1d1d}body #challenge-success-text{background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIzMiIgaGVpZ2h0PSIzMiIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI2IDI2Ij48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjZDlkOWQ5IiBkPSJNMTMgMGExMyAxMyAwIDEgMCAwIDI2IDEzIDEzIDAgMCAwIDAtMjZtMCAyNGExMSAxMSAwIDEgMSAwLTIyIDExIDExIDAgMCAxIDAgMjIiLz48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjZDlkOWQ5IiBkPSJtMTAuOTU1IDE2LjA1NS0zLjk1LTQuMTI1LTEuNDQ1IDEuMzg1IDUuMzcgNS42MSA5LjQ5NS05LjYtMS40Mi0xLjQwNXoiLz48L3N2Zz4=)}body #challenge-error-text{background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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)}}body{display:flex;flex-direction:column;min-height:100vh}body.no-js .loading-spinner{visibility:hidden}body.no-js .challenge-running{display:none}body.dark{background-color:#222;color:#d9d9d9}body.dark a{color:#fff}body.dark a:hover{color:#ee730a;text-decoration:underline}body.dark .lds-ring div{border-color:#999 transparent transparent}body.dark .font-red{color:#b20f03}body.dark .pow-button{background-color:#4693ff;color:#1d1d1d}body.dark #challenge-success-text{background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIzMiIgaGVpZ2h0PSIzMiIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI2IDI2Ij48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjZDlkOWQ5IiBkPSJNMTMgMGExMyAxMyAwIDEgMCAwIDI2IDEzIDEzIDAgMCAwIDAtMjZtMCAyNGExMSAxMSAwIDEgMSAwLTIyIDExIDExIDAgMCAxIDAgMjIiLz48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjZDlkOWQ5IiBkPSJtMTAuOTU1IDE2LjA1NS0zLjk1LTQuMTI1LTEuNDQ1IDEuMzg1IDUuMzcgNS42MSA5LjQ5NS05LjYtMS40Mi0xLjQwNXoiLz48L3N2Zz4=)}body.dark #challenge-error-text{background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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)}body.light{background-color:transparent;color:#313131}body.light a{color:#0051c3}body.light a:hover{color:#ee730a;text-decoration:underline}body.light .lds-ring div{border-color:#595959 transparent transparent}body.light .font-red{color:#fc574a}body.light .pow-button{background-color:#003681;border-color:#003681;color:#fff}body.light #challenge-success-text{background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIzMiIgaGVpZ2h0PSIzMiIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI2IDI2Ij48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjMzEzMTMxIiBkPSJNMTMgMGExMyAxMyAwIDEgMCAwIDI2IDEzIDEzIDAgMCAwIDAtMjZtMCAyNGExMSAxMSAwIDEgMSAwLTIyIDExIDExIDAgMCAxIDAgMjIiLz48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjMzEzMTMxIiBkPSJtMTAuOTU1IDE2LjA1NS0zLjk1LTQuMTI1LTEuNDQ1IDEuMzg1IDUuMzcgNS42MSA5LjQ5NS05LjYtMS40Mi0xLjQwNXoiLz48L3N2Zz4=)}body.light #challenge-error-text{background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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)}a{background-color:transparent;color:#0051c3;text-decoration:none;transition:color .15s ease}a:hover{color:#ee730a;text-decoration:underline}.main-content{margin:8rem auto;max-width:60rem;width:100%}.heading-favicon{height:2rem;margin-right:.5rem;width:2rem}@media (width <= 720px){.main-content{margin-top:4rem}.heading-favicon{height:1.5rem;width:1.5rem}}.footer,.main-content{padding-left:1.5rem;padding-right:1.5rem}.main-wrapper{align-items:center;display:flex;flex:1;flex-direction:column}.font-red{color:#b20f03}.spacer{margin:2rem 0}.h1{font-size:2.5rem;font-weight:500;line-height:3.75rem}.h2{font-weight:500}.core-msg,.h2{font-size:1.5rem;line-height:2.25rem}.body-text,.core-msg{font-weight:400}.body-text{font-size:1rem;line-height:1.25rem}@media (width <= 720px){.h1{font-size:1.5rem;line-height:1.75rem}.h2{font-size:1.25rem}.core-msg,.h2{line-height:1.5rem}.core-msg{font-size:1rem}}#challenge-error-text{background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);padding-left:34px}#challenge-error-text,#challenge-success-text{background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:contain}#challenge-success-text{background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIzMiIgaGVpZ2h0PSIzMiIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI2IDI2Ij48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjMzEzMTMxIiBkPSJNMTMgMGExMyAxMyAwIDEgMCAwIDI2IDEzIDEzIDAgMCAwIDAtMjZtMCAyNGExMSAxMSAwIDEgMSAwLTIyIDExIDExIDAgMCAxIDAgMjIiLz48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjMzEzMTMxIiBkPSJtMTAuOTU1IDE2LjA1NS0zLjk1LTQuMTI1LTEuNDQ1IDEuMzg1IDUuMzcgNS42MSA5LjQ5NS05LjYtMS40Mi0xLjQwNXoiLz48L3N2Zz4=);padding-left:42px}.text-center{text-align:center}.pow-button{background-color:#0051c3;border:.063rem solid #0051c3;border-radius:.313rem;color:#fff;font-size:.875rem;line-height:1.313rem;margin:2rem 0;padding:.375rem 1rem;transition-duration:.2s;transition-property:background-color,border-color,color;transition-timing-function:ease}.pow-button:hover{background-color:#003681;border-color:#003681;color:#fff;cursor:pointer}.footer{font-size:.75rem;line-height:1.125rem;margin:0 auto;max-width:60rem;width:100%}.footer-inner{border-top:1px solid #d9d9d9;padding-bottom:1rem;padding-top:1rem}.clearfix:after{clear:both;content:"";display:table}.clearfix .column{float:left;padding-right:1.5rem;width:50%}.diagnostic-wrapper{margin-bottom:.5rem}.footer .ray-id{text-align:center}.footer .ray-id code{font-family:monaco,courier,monospace}.core-msg,.zone-name-title{overflow-wrap:break-word}@media (width <= 720px){.diagnostic-wrapper{display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;justify-content:center}.clearfix:after{clear:none;content:none;display:initial;text-align:center}.column{padding-bottom:2rem}.clearfix .column{float:none;padding:0;width:auto;word-break:keep-all}.zone-name-title{margin-bottom:1rem}}.loading-spinner{height:76.391px}.lds-ring{display:inline-block;position:relative}.lds-ring,.lds-ring div{height:1.875rem;width:1.875rem}.lds-ring div{animation:lds-ring 1.2s cubic-bezier(.5,0,.5,1) infinite;border:.3rem solid transparent;border-radius:50%;border-top-color:#313131;box-sizing:border-box;display:block;position:absolute}.lds-ring div:first-child{animation-delay:-.45s}.lds-ring div:nth-child(2){animation-delay:-.3s}.lds-ring div:nth-child(3){animation-delay:-.15s}@keyframes lds-ring{0%{transform:rotate(0)}to{transform:rotate(1turn)}}@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast:active),screen and (-ms-high-contrast:none){.main-wrapper,body{display:block}}.rtl .heading-favicon{margin-left:.5rem;margin-right:0}.rtl #challenge-success-text{background-position:100%;padding-left:0;padding-right:42px}.rtl #challenge-error-text{background-position:100%;padding-left:0;padding-right:34px}</style><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="390"></head><body class="no-js"><div class="main-wrapper" role="main"><div class="main-content"><noscript><div id="challenge-error-title"><div class="h2"><span id="challenge-error-text">Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue</span></div></div></noscript></div></div><script>(function(){window._cf_chl_opt={cvId: '3',cZone: "www.tesourodireto.com.br",cType: 'managed',cNounce: '76219',cRay: '8b6caaba8b6c4569',cHash: '50c0574b9612071',cUPMDTk: "\/json\/br\/com\/b3\/tesourodireto\/service\/api\/treasurybondsinfo.json?__cf_chl_tk=Z1rjPqvq_qDEPl46KoOiMrbWu6TCf13e_gLcd1PoU0Q-1724264738-0.0.1.1-5140",cFPWv: 'b',cTTimeMs: '1000',cMTimeMs: '390000',cTplV: 5,cTplB: 'cf',cK: "",fa: "\/json\/br\/com\/b3\/tesourodireto\/service\/api\/treasurybondsinfo.json?__cf_chl_f_tk=Z1rjPqvq_qDEPl46KoOiMrbWu6TCf13e_gLcd1PoU0Q-1724264738-0.0.1.1-5140",md: "iuP1RSDi1HngotKZf1Ya.rrul.cu4WlvbLb7lKg8Wg0-1724264738-1.1.1.1-ZipTd8hsRMUm9w2mKTNTL.grWDkCxYW7wGviMyY4952u1YqtgT1tCzfgWyeLk7NaZDhZtYIjcMx9faN9jK2ZBpXiqdjVqvsJqv.mO0kAytAZ1CB2Ddf4q34DPcGDKyG_wyViWgvHfOqiaFNjKf1O.66wJ7qFEJmtruQx36cRe17hZyC_sORUOofzAxUvF2l6Oow1W7mB__6k4MmLIVh43_2j5SYkiJ1hh9xg81VyizePuntwmWyAHWWHHZMXXMcob56HcTJ4YIY7NThaWLLb0m4vr6_bZkmX36cSOCbPb47kErih04iQObZ1TfSdThGJTYBFQbavflULZ33kEEPUM8Z2YxNqN8bvWnrwxraHmdxxoCRX81l9BmNNZMpdKRrDnJWFdcRPH8c7mp3zHVytWDvuEOpMGkDMDM8bYu2.oBJcNGyFjGVneZ0CtLl7tHlNIoqAJNnhLT5eE694no5j.AS_N55Su.xWwQiS8jp6tqXl13a1CpmP_NDmJJ5PJPR_Xop1GVOT.eLhU695m1iD0L27PqVWwUrPmm.IirKf2Mw.E7bCi1iW6zLXEpF5D_Pn_0qQyVQ0svDzy6.8TwEGK_kjF2Yld9uWkBFFqW4rWZfdUkgmRnc1Y5eXzNLfzKbMWiR38pIEcC0kfLjaVDvWlIkfq5.iQkm0F88Zryu4UvLwso_tkIlMv5g1dj_nqmSG1Xtl5Us8._780__Oq1iUCAAhkdXbIeuf.n_MJO2st4vpe7.UGhJdUprNvD__JrT0LaG0_lZ5MT_V6bSKfu1wfCnyNGng3UdW0HDliT0kAG9C3hZyAKlFkAe7FkAkWST3Pol6ygPueTq5FWo_imY__DC4G1v3msj4tCNRO4GUe14k2kOpLZ3CpoIyeZa0D2PXgyj7eemXFvQUIpNACxHWdryPujs8JpwHT4rIOI545RNqVC3rNzcEv25uP9Y8Sy38Q2gLt1SRiFPnb6rQqDLJXUV35YTpzmxl7JilISrO03.X8eO2756LAWh70QTlqa2GQDs2XlnAbdT1QgNWF89xHdXeX00Z2vc2L9CfkMnAxPZcOKhwQHmGDsL6igBJWeJ1CYFshReF0DZjnWqbxuiiaLVEpckcyTklduvg13X4ZnItNM7q51eFr_kN0045mAJWRQUmdp7LVRaELcKVmBB0yg6tbHmC_iCiTf2kwe9plNEyQrKXtapvv0HOmwMebNjZd.vSXiZkk9EsU4KAIYdiaAF_DJGXk9O9PYWz2A3hdrBXLhpUqKdp2gfRV8pdt7Ayjm1y5CY9wTOoKAervbZkPLQLFX7K_fbSaVQZ3L7pJngsXxfEoq5hmv8Kg67JtG3jmoB22KZaCrC9Udx3GDbrVhrYzAL736bYNMAc_3Xyxkn3cfS6ZvoNeWItTHqy_Y7Td99NDKGqZ2phEU0opQCGxAb0V.uIQub.uoyBKnoQ4WrWK6vlAQ0lZNT88leHq5OSSdEjO4kcQgZ.UAVuQikDoNpLyIOUXCAiNYbkJXVprN6h1Guxw7FiRpusUUknIysNMteaw5e.N29d22dOR0LtQeT.mOvVrBkyXgrnnf637ykr4JqB79LDOzwPkppLDED5ffMNnNP3oy1ZkFyVy_GnfPl6gD5MUubfMF6ziT1CReUxHVpM8xiCcCfz0bcoc.jlNq.8Ir4x_vFHgiZShd8CRY2DzzmR.WLno_W6eNFpWuE2DXiV4F8Yea7RBdTVSGYo2OkdAjGPy3RsScbVyeaviI2TYzs5WEvYfse2v3vNHyNHQb1n05UtQ.Jkrxdnl0nAtfO9cbgt1nKt8PyCvVhPlL35GRZpOXU5VxmIaNP6v04G.yFTFLEPLX3B3oUvRdPbRIfjWtzipS8iUnV4F2d2gbTw27pCYJbLz6.8DU.3d4I0PjO.ySYYbqpbpLIQ2R7ZWAYxO3tPr_6xaklENg_HIZKPaRTqEYIEos45lxI.aXFKU16iDuGN6uQNBiteCrKCVd976VisnQh3efpsGDHlANWuF7F4K.nxrO4RzowUXq35C9O9KKlDNHxHk3Q48Huu1mZvTTK6A5VguWvhpIHt3Y5l9Iua25o3W1pSaANEbkUebdczSEdwbZy.rugDJQYelkh.F98Ty_scMGyOSs2PnSFnnDTpDleMCjq_WKG_GZNeHTgypfs6d5feIZIgUXA2iP1GgT.1NNB8hP70RokWBTRKYESJbJxjDBYh.K9nKTt5mdQ47Q8ABQxRJmmt67o0Sp9OAYQqjTBvnKlLNqHc.Jrr__fJKbr5_t45gHYLeVligv9I504Oq_39N8jD8S_IlzobQrBAMjBP7EdO78mhH4nBu1WY6lT06xRvrk9e.GIBee72jPXstDb22fukqQO2ew3ykv6SnxoF89.4xBu_ZFcpuBx7Fpk0pfS_D9l7ka4Teao9Oqu9PhlnoiDtJ0cZD4aB0b2UzQafSRwXR7BFGCBWt01hyT2bHqcgJaTEKA0qZa0o5sbjJumHorDEts2qpqzzMHWSnqezVBJhdxoBvBFb.boxNJvYQry8TFYlsbzZZ9fEUHdYOO5jyJnmwDIjtD3P89Vh2.slqeYibQqPk_x8k.1XpaZan8zUEvu.ty.Fypd2DabB8Rp.tWRtwAywhRWhw6pIJ7AlrGCjteuFjwqix38cyR5v914BQzq30x9o7F2Cnj6XDqQYOxeyJX749BRdHVQyFZz2J7yi1_w6NMSD6alDVf2dDImyRTJb9V6d5DJc.3jAzP0V1yrGSBfq5sWViy.ZmhuJ5LtPA4MY0_1lXkVgSP5JRmfRGrpFuwZtID7qoEMPWJ90l7iRrGAJ4XvVgMXjNR3pKWvdZMz50mn_E6yH7zhx7IrmbXmJVVA",mdrd: "v0yBEgCDEl6Nen6wEw5079.h1f2wr48IVgmWcbwk4DE-1724264738-1.1.1.1-UW9CWrL9AdFb41w8e_j7G.tdStKG6OIFbPJSVN7xjVxvgTSPiTO9jB4SQzHc8h_I_Uc.4cF95NRmHJdrwBeAiDWcagFTBCLlm1rKXkJY5pg8V2iaMOdT4KzdBhk8ABhEAe7VZPp6tuJtJnP8.5dDq0BwNmhldH.ovlCAaaMg83oGdm9_2d0LeEqw0BfTASHF_UtiPr1tVu4RW3Facv6YwldUXqaXvGxrMLjtaaIX9DAADKhU_RBH7Je0hgEfHpnhbi4st1o0YsJBJ8d_Aan6fFpX9GYwCs2w0FIA74w_JuOMM0OvuN.4p0dM.ZhJ_QwR5LnyZqgLvs1FPk8UYtlUKpPeT_bh_X6XERLmk0TAGiY89Sj6NKvYygB0QVzkRMYl0SKbk5yOPrKxVTpEjdDK.IDOv7H0BS7nwURXOJKzgD.DxaVkWvPS3EfKx9AeYzasZfP7wBcvT1wm4gZj72B.UQljUmJlrRhfmJARwln89K4xjK6mIIg2i.4exAEYScRss7qAZXHW9jor2JD5S9XCLYKjr7JJTPo.lm2ZGY5A5o2CXnN927c8HeMH3BwFxbJsX5pQE3NpW6cfgi9B0PkBG8YFPf3bmopk687JRGaywg3x5MgydMjSW03wikqEYOuRlgfEYaRST4Yiywe9eMnIP9BuKVmyKN2PuvxqAfB4kRKbLFD894wp9PNgumvyZP_SMl7DcQ_KMmOdxlYxnIdrGAsJY_FgY_7S4o3ZUcpMEXSKfU80WYpgAD.lKc7QeajWF9vTErgjR3OcrpqrlqTG5xGjRkFzMTKyVPR_wYKQo4h6YnxIcZObqHNBRYyZ29NoLhMLPeaqS52elXW0sJjEAtN208qLB4A3maIad9ssT3492Wf735zXOH0UkGUBxLUUu_KNtLzzJ.quKMhucLOyAbwDtZro3i0VRMrBEmsCH7wZczvtkHE2wEjl.9qOwJ_CmDalvg7wcLrhQ6BDaX5amB_OmlaY4o9jcd.pOH7ixm41n2TdMFDPW6Z4PY1JQvOX4A7vCqwVnWEGr0qmWWOVNKqHMHa0WZlEaPo_EdXHcBIgH5FaIQMUbSJ67dXn4bCPcBlam8BbA1uyiXkqFmVHr6RjsBA6ynlAWXeLBxTt1yomG00fplaLLMPtN_CFjg2hoYsxVpBucpA5ecPLFOvADq5xcwfS06D2S41zr8o.Y0y.4_SPGb48vr_qDCEz45lD5hrlwTeRJx7tUjHBArk.HdMDJmRSfIKc9bhP89LV6q6HUYsKohow3x2coCqTL.3LcTYkGbv8I2mUird94Qg8aDy_MqqCkQOSTmajAi_AFk0AkfXYM.czf3z6F8ALS2vkC1b3Py8VFlh56hTMD9qgfknOzFIsMJeP...1hvrj0Swq1wh1LGjxfhVChtcRROsvT2C_5tX2lxViGrGcmIq70Z.xi301vZegoNypqJIwPtiveSyEIh4LhTftQzgjS1k0bdSsGV3qQUB3gOjMd3tks3e_ent7hKehbGuY9PDFW_Of6ewiDZ.AqWWHoeunra3KdRMxINv_wKGYADNHT.GzPQIDWJ.X8cgdmnOfcRU1HXa4bN.SCJm4qcfr0xbGAJnTiQkWVYwzoyUE2CkQC1qcSdS9JKjsNvg7Pu47r2nUfUQhwBzXK2wrLH69CHOlfBQCG2YzvzrL7emqSGb63X8hyzgZUiRPeP7aa3uqGITjqV8wIMeqwFUxHfGL73M58KB.k733DrssYe1rF_gc0SKhIQx4b.txjgij4C_QRqCri4GqwZmBTwywyG5mvYClzST4C8qmKpsLvu2VnV.kVR1dV5oiopAXvSfd5RTVc.qbg91R3.nqB.Qi3a69YIAo4SKgtOBevaR8UV_RYJ4tp7FReEa2jIpIoekxBPpA7bA.VdUWhatkAB6lV_V2In6UDRi3QNmnyLfeCPmd6WT99iOyuvw8.QtvdAe10NqbEgqyeYSaI8BL6Q0maoFhfo9kl1HUntI6DiuZQwVWjpHG9CGwIGx40isfNlgbSZ1loMSJXj_EmaIhcERFQWFMJPLdPx19fRp5OwnX8hl72Tcjy4LE6IGmcsTEigggYMIrregt61prC00XSo1FUlP97adwOgHqCHvF5b1LAfRtZSdBxBRcLJWtRMA4iiqTd1ppOIAaRF0",cRq: {ru: 'aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGVzb3Vyb2RpcmV0by5jb20uYnIvanNvbi9ici9jb20vYjMvdGVzb3Vyb2RpcmV0by9zZXJ2aWNlL2FwaS90cmVhc3VyeWJvbmRzaW5mby5qc29u',ra: 'TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKGNvbXBhdGlibGU7IEdvb2dsZS1BcHBzLVNjcmlwdDsgYmVhbnNlcnZlcjsgK2h0dHBzOi8vc2NyaXB0Lmdvb2dsZS5jb207IGlkOiBVQUVtZERkX1NVaXJxRkZCd0tKMmtmYWoyQVdHQ2NmejEtUSk=',d: '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',t: 'MTcyNDI2NDczOC4wMDAwMDA=',cT: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),m: 'rnqArQ5VyEUxhVDcUZk5uCSd9V3Ck7KN35WAcTCmqF8=',i1: '1Jro30yblwFRNIYlXY++9A==',i2: 'sK81MhGkyhpHQGJBYM2mlw==',zh: 'jz5Gp3bec+Y6nCfo63lUnVAazAcaWUHHOPWqyRTbhbg=',uh: '1oP4aHiJ/18kwUGrh6q3uZyWNUq0/eo4sfGh+gGAGSI=',hh: '8gXui11nEZU8j307Ch03nitlY6SqMpM+QY8u7ADCc64=',}};var cpo = document.createElement('script');cpo.src = '/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/orchestrate/chl_page/v1?ray=8b6caaba8b6c4569';window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash = location.hash === '' && location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search === '' && location.href.slice(0, location.href.length - window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash.length).indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '?' : location.search;if (window.history && window.history.replaceState) {var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;history.replaceState(null, null, "\/json\/br\/com\/b3\/tesourodireto\/service\/api\/treasurybondsinfo.json?__cf_chl_rt_tk=Z1rjPqvq_qDEPl46KoOiMrbWu6TCf13e_gLcd1PoU0Q-1724264738-0.0.1.1-5140" + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash);cpo.onload = function() {history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);}}document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);}());</script></body></html>



Notice this is a public JSON API, I am able to call it directly from browser without problems:
https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/json/br/com/b3/tesourodireto/service/api/treasurybondsinfo.json
I guess the domain started to block the calls from Google Script server.
I was wondering if there is any way to bypass/workaround it, calling this JSON API from another public REST API first, then calling this intermediate API on my Google Script function.
So the new code would be something like this:
function TESOURODIRETO() {
  let srcURL = "https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/json/br/com/b3/tesourodireto/service/api/treasurybondsinfo.json";
  let intermediate_API = "<REST_API>"
  let jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(intermediate_API + srcURL);
}

I tried to find an REST API to perform this workaround/bypass, but I am unable to find it.

UPDATE: Thank you all who commented/replied on this question. With the Full HTML added above, it is clear now the reason of this exception:
The public API is indeed trying to check if it is a human calling for it (Cloudflare platform). But this does not make sense at all, it goes against the concept of an API, right?
And I understand that the proper way to fix this would be to contact the API admin to change Cloudflare settings to allow the call from another application/google-script. But here is another problem: "www.tesourodireto.com.br" is basically the Brazilian treasury website, and the public service from this/my country is really bad on answering/resolving issues like this. We (the guys engaged on the original git:https://gist.github.com/lucashmsilva/9f4596f2924ac5c1eb0721c2c41dc257?permalink_comment_id=5162243#gistcomment-5162243) are already discussing/trying to contact the admin to try to solve this.
That is why I am trying to find a workaround/bypass for this problem.

For more context of how this code is used, refer to this link (this page language is portuguese but a auto-translator should be enough just to get the context): https://gist.github.com/lucashmsilva/9f4596f2924ac5c1eb0721c2c41dc257?permalink_comment_id=5162243#gistcomment-5162243

Please describe how the function is run. P.D. You should use muteHttpExceptions to get the full error message. Regarding using other Service to make the API calle, that makes the question too broad and off -topic.

Could you [edit] to add the full html?

@TheMaster done, and thanks it is clear now, I can see it is trying to validate that I am an human. But this makes no sense: an API that tries to check if it is an human using it

Also tried this youtube guide: Scrape Websites with 403 Errors and bypass cloudflare https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OF100qsZPdI
It does work on localmachine but did not when moving the code to pythonanywhere.com

You should be able to post other questions about the problems you found using what you learned from the video. Remember that questions on this site should be about a specific problem unique to programming, so start with one specific question.

From the question

The public API is indeed trying to check if it is a human calling for it (Cloudflare platform). But this does not make sense at all, it goes against the concept of an API, right?

If there is no official documentation for https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/json/br/com/b3/tesourodireto/service/api/treasurybondsinfo.json then it's very likely that it is not intended to be used the way you are trying to do it.
The site administrators may have noticed something they did not like about the above URL and requested the developers add the captcha.
When in doubt, reaching out to the website support team is the best course of action. They can provide the necessary guidance and support.
Unfortunately, Google Apps Script does not offer much as a workaround, as the options to customize HTTP requests are limited. For example, using a custom user agent is not possible.
Try using other tools like Postman or learning about tools to automate web browsers like Selenium. Once you get the required response, then you might use the Google Sheets API to store the data in Google Sheets.
Related

Google Apps Script: 403 in simple UrlFetchApp.fetch


Using UrlFetch with Error Handling
This function makes an HTTP request to the URL you have provided, I have added the required options that are being asked from you to get a response. Along with correcting the format on using UrlFetch.
Replication:
During the replication process. It seems that the URL endpoint was asking for an option muteHttpException in order for it to go through the URL. Following what was required through this replication process. I have added correct options that was being asked from the URL endpoint.

Sample code:
function myFunction() {
  options = {muteHttpExceptions: true};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/json/br/com/b3/tesourodireto/service/api/treasurybondsinfo.json", options);
  console.log(response.getContentText())
}

Output:

References:
UrlFetchApp
When should you set muteHTTPExceptions to true?

This doesn't answer the question. You should at least make a html file in Google drive using the given response and examine the html in a browser. I suspect it's a cloudflare captcha of some sort.

I understand that it wasn't that clear on providing whole information about the answer. Let me edit the post to include what I have found out during the process of replicating the issue.

thank you for trying @JatsPPG, but yes I tried to add this option too, it did not return anything I judged useful to resolve this. I was hoping for a answer to provide an intermediate API that could solve this, like a proxy or something.

May I ask during the time that you've tried running this recommendation, what type of error did you receive? Because, I am also using AppScript and during the replication I haven't received any errors. I want to understand your situation. Feel free to edit your post to provide more clarification regarding your situation.

@JatsPPG Please call the link in the description directly in your browser, that is the output expected for this function in google script, that is the result I was getting some days ago. Thing is you are just catching the exception when you use the option to enable muteHttpExceptions, the output using this option is not the json expected.

intermediate API that could solve this, like a proxy or  Not sure about this, but [tag:APIGEE] might be relevant. @RafaelGuimaraesdePaula
