UrlFetchApp in Google Apps Script resulting in 403 Error
I use UrlFetch on a plain looking site https://www.financecharts.com/stocks/AAPL/all-metrics/ as follows
try {
  var content4 = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.financecharts.com/stocks/" + ticker + "/all-metrics/").getContentText();
  //other code here
} catch (error) {
  Logger.log('Error fetching data: ' + error);
  return null;
}

and it keeps returning the error:

Error fetching data: Exception: Request failed for https://www.financecharts.com returned code 403. Truncated server response: Just a moment...<meta htt... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Any idea what to do for a successful fetch?

Perhaps the data is rendered after the page is loaded

and in that case, fetch is not possible?

Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78897095/bypass-workaround-for-urlfetchapp-request-failed-returned-code-403

Replace the fetch line with var content4 = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.financecharts.com/stocks/" + ticker + "/all-metrics/", { 'muteHttpExceptions': true, }).getContentText(); and you gonna get the page, but I 'm afraid not the one you want. You will need to analize content4 to undesrstand how to follow from there.

thank you for your input. I guess not possible to fetch that page by google apps script
